# Cannot find commons logging class

Tags: java, maven

It's strange. I just changed some stuff in my web application and can't revert the stuff because I can't remember what I've changed.

I'm getting this exception when trying to run my webapp:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:270)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1701)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1546)
    ... 12 more
```

Here's my pom.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <name>example</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.6</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <spring.version>3.1.1.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.4</slf4j.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>                       
        </dependency>

        <!-- Wro4j -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ro.isdc.wro4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>wro4j-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.7</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.1-901-1.jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache Tiles -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 303 with Hibernate Validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSR 250 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr250-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Custom tag libraries -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.slugify</groupId>
            <artifactId>slugify-taglib</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Joda Time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I just remember that I added Joda Time and JSR 250 API but both doesn't have any dependency on commons-logging?!

If some more code is needed just tell and I'll provide.

**EDIT**

Dependency tree:

```
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:provided (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-asm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-web:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-core:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.security:spring-security-config:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-extensions:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- ro.isdc.wro4j:wro4j-core:jar:1.4.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-pool:commons-pool:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.javascript:closure-compiler:jar:r1918:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- args4j:args4j:jar:2.0.12:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:10.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.4.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.json:json:jar:20090211:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.ant:ant:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.ant:ant-launcher:jar:1.8.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.jarjar:jarjar:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7R3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.lltyk:dojo-shrinksafe:jar:1.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jruby:jruby-complete:jar:1.6.7.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- me.n4u.sass:sass-gems:jar:3.1.16:compile
[INFO] |  +- nz.co.edmi:bourbon-gem-jar:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-1.7:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-support:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.gmaven.feature:gmaven-feature-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-support:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.codehaus.gmaven.runtime:gmaven-runtime-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.sonatype.gshell:gshell-io:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.codehaus.plexus:plexus-utils:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.thoughtworks.qdox:qdox:jar:1.10:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:1.7.4:compile
[INFO] |     \- jline:jline:jar:0.9.94:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:jar:1.6.6:runtime (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] +- log4j:log4j:jar:1.2.17:runtime
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:4.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.1.0.GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.1_spec:jar:1.0.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- dom4j:dom4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- xml-apis:xml-apis:jar:1.0.b2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.javax.persistence:hibernate-jpa-2.0-api:jar:1.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.15.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:4.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- postgresql:postgresql:jar:9.1-901-1.jdbc4:compile
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.5:provided
[INFO] +- javax.servlet:jstl:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-jsp:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tiles:tiles-servlet:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-core:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.8.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-template:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tiles:tiles-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.0.0.GA:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:4.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] +- junit:junit:jar:4.10:test (scope not updated to compile)
[INFO] |  \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.1:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:3.1.1.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- commons-dbcp:commons-dbcp:jar:1.4:test
[INFO] +- com.github.slugify:slugify-taglib:jar:1.0-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.slugify:slugify:jar:1.0-RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.1:compile
```

**EDIT 2**

Commenting out all spring-security related stuff results in this runtime exception (replaced all exclusions by commons-logging dependency with scope `provided`):

```
Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextDestroyed(ContextLoaderListener.java:144)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:4819)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stopInternal(StandardContext.java:5466)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.stop(LifecycleBase.java:232)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.slf4j.LoggerFactory could not be successfully initialized. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#unsuccessfulInit
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory(LoggerFactory.java:303)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:269)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:156)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.SLF4JLogFactory.getInstance(SLF4JLogFactory.java:132)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory.getLog(LogFactory.java:272)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextCleanupListener.<clinit>(ContextCleanupListener.java:43)
    ... 12 more
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be an IDE error... I've used Eclipse with WTP and Maven. There was a tmp0 and tmp1 folder, I recreated the workspace. Now it's working again... Strange issue.

Comment: Facing same issue. Where were `tmp0` and `tmp1`? And how exactly do you recreate a workspace in eclipse? Do you mean create a new workspace?

Comment: Hm thats long ago. I can find a tmp0 folder here: `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core` - but I don't know how I recreated the workspace anymore. Sorry.

Comment: Ok, no prob. I ended up deleting maven repo at `~/.m2` and updated maven dependencies via eclipse and it started working fine. I had done some clean-up using mvn command line commands on an eclipse project which was using m2eclipse. Seems like m2eclipse and mvn commands do not work well together.

Answer (score 2):

Option 2 from [this](http://www.slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL) page may help you.

> Commons-logging can be rather simply and conveniently excluded as a dependency by declaring it in the provided scope within the pom.xml file of your project. The actual commons-logging classes would be provided by jcl-over-slf4j.

(see link for example POM snippet)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing exclusion for commons-logging in pom and the exception is also saying that it cannot find the jar for commons-logging. Do check that

Comment: that's why I'm asking here. I can't find any dependency which has commons-logging as dependency. So where does this commons-logging dependency come from?

Comment: Have you tried `mvn dependency:tree`? Also, what happens when you don't exclude `commons-logging` in your POM?

Comment: you can see the dependency tree in my post above

Answer (score 0):

It looks like spring-webmvc also has a dependency on commons-logging.  You should add an exclusion for it like you have for spring-framework and spring-security.

Comment: There's no exclusion in the travel sample as well: https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-samples/travel/pom.xml